# file.readlines() returns an empty list despite seek(0)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read a file that already exists line by line. I have checked various options on Stackoverflow where they have mentioned to add `<file>.seek(0)`. This points the code to the beginning of the file. I have added this functionality as well in my code but still, it returns an empty list. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Tried `seek(0)` but it does not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess

class ListDirectories:
        def trash_listing(self):
                hdfs_listing_file = open('abc.txt', 'w+')
                subprocess.Popen("hdfs dfs -du -s -h /user/*/.Trash", stdout=hdfs_listing_file, shell=True)
                hdfs_listing_file.close()

tl = ListDirectories()
tl.trash_listing()

class DirectoryFiltering:
        def file_filtering(self):
                with open('abc.txt', 'r') as myfile:
                        myfile.seek(0)
                        lines = myfile.readlines()
                print(myfile)
                print(lines)

df = DirectoryFiltering()
df.file_filtering()
```

I would expect it to give an output something like:

```
0 0 /user/abc/.Trash
24 M 72 M /user/def/.Trash
```

Instead, it gives `[]` as an output.

Comment: dumb question: have you opened the file in an editor and checked that it is not empty?

Comment: You don`t need the `seek`. Is the file correctly open? Check if it is in the same directory as the python file. Does the file contain any text?

Comment: @Flob Yes obviously the file has contents with about 30 lines in it

Comment: @UliSotschok Yes it is correctly open and it also shows the same once I run my code. Also my python file and the .txt file are in the same directory. Yes the file consists of about 30 lines

Comment: have you tried just executing the `with open(...` block

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with the subprocess you are dealing with. The file reading (except the seek) is definitely correct and will work on an existing file. Maybe you open it, before the subprocess has written to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't waiting for the program to produce output to the file or exit before attempting to read it.

The function that produces the output to the file should either keep track of the process so it can be waited on or wait on it there. That is the wait call may be delayed until just before the file is needed to be read.

The following waits after closing the opened file. Sure one should use a `with open() as` here.

```
class ListDirectories:

        def trash_listing(self):

                hdfs_listing_file = open('abc.txt', 'w+')
                p = subprocess.Popen("hdfs dfs -du -s -h /user/*/.Trash", stdout=hdfs_listing_file, shell=True)
                hdfs_listing_file.close()
                p.wait()
```

Comment: That worked. Thanks a ton! I think that was the issue that before ingesting it in the file it was trying to read it. Is there in any way I can also mention the timeout duration in .wait() ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
def file_filtering(self):
    with open('abc.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        lines = myfile.readlines()
        print(myfile)
```